# Story Board or without Story Board

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been making the native iPhone app and I have never used a xib, I mainly used to make the application in run time based, but know with the introduction of Main Story Board. I just want to know which one will be easier for using run time based which I mainly used to or start  using story board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll *probably* want to use a Storyboard(s) in the long run. However, there are pros and cons:

### Pros

1. You can see your **whole project**
2. You avoid a *whole lot of nasty code*
3. You can visually 'hook' stuff together

### Cons

1. Only available **>iOS 5.0** <<<<***Huge!***

In my personal experience, **I usually use Storyboards** - the percentage of devices running < iOS 5 is actually quite low.

Answer (score 2):

Both have its own advantage and Storyboard has more options and ease when used in the right way (that is why it is introduced!).

**By using storyboard**

- You can avoid so **many** line of code for page navigation and all
- Complete picture of project is visible

**By xib**

- Used a lot and hence more easy
- Independent,so can be worked better
- For working as a team xib is preferrable since the conflicts can be less if each team member working in seperate files

**MY SOLUTION**
Since it is possible to use both in same project. I use **both** in my projects. To take the both advantages according to my requirement.